# Mongodb query, flatten objects with array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

A document:

```
{
   objectId: 35,
   properties: [
     {
       pset: 'A1',
       property: 'Fire',
       value: '60'
     },
     {
       pset: 'B1',
       property: 'Fire',
       value: '70'
     }  
   ]
}
```

Input to query:

```
{ 
   psetsWithProperties: [{ pset: 'A1', property: 'Fire'}, { pset: 'abc', property: 'fff'}]
}
```

The combination of pset and property is always uniq. So there can not be two 'A1' and 'Fire' in the properties collection.

Expected output:

```
[{
  objectId: 35,
  properties: {
    'A1/Fire': '60'
  }
}]
```

So the second item (B1, Fire) is not included since it's not in the input.

If there is no match at all, the properties object is empty:

```
[{
  objectId: 35,
  properties: {}
}]
```

The MongoDB aggregation framework should be used here.

Something with `$in, $group, $unwind` I think.

Don't really know where to start.

Does not have to be exactly as in my examples.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify: why `objectId: 35` and do you really need to convert from `'60'` to `60` ?

Comment: @mickl Sorry, mistyping. Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match an array against another array you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) with [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html). Then to generate JSON key values dynamically you need [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) operator, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            objectId: 1,
            data: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$properties",
                    as: "docProp",
                    cond: {
                        $anyElementTrue: {
                            $map: {
                                input: [{ pset: 'A1', property: 'Fire'}, { pset: 'abc', property: 'fff'}],
                                as: "paramProp",
                                in: {
                                    $and: [
                                        { $eq: [ "$$docProp.pset", "$$paramProp.pset" ] },
                                        { $eq: [ "$$docProp.property", "$$paramProp.property" ] },
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            objectId: 1,
            properties: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$data",
                        in: {
                            k: { $concat: [ "$$this.pset", "/", "$$this.property" ] },
                            v: "$$this.value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Wow, thats fast. Workday has come to an end. I'll try it out tomorrow (and accept answer if it works). Thx!